# using tokio:: spawn function not executing

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

this code：

```
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};
use tokio::time::Duration;

static REQUEST_RECV_V2: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

async fn no_msg_pro(s: String) {
    println!("exectue no_msg_pro fun - str: {} begin!", s);
    tokio::time::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    //sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5));
    println!("exectue no_msg_pro fun - str: {} end!", s);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        loop {
            sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(10));
            REQUEST_RECV_V2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            let s = format!("value--{:?}", REQUEST_RECV_V2);
            println!("run process_msg fun - handle: {:?}", s);
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                no_msg_pro(s).await;
            });
        }
    });

    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(100)).await;
}
```

When running the code, the function `no_msg_pro` will not be triggered when entering the loop for the first time, only when entering the loop for the second time the function `no_msg_pro` will run.
get result this:

```
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--1"
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--2"
exectue no_msg_pro fun - str: value--1 begin!
exectue no_msg_pro fun - str: value--1 end!
```

I dont know why it,s , can you show me the reason!

Comment: You are using **blocking** `sleep` from `std::thread`. In `async` code you should avoid blocking thread. Use [tokio::time::sleep](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html), or other async compatible version, instead.

Comment: thank your answer。but try your advice get the same result：
`run process_msg fun - handle: "value--1"
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--2"
exectue no_msg_pro fun - str: value--1 begin!`

Comment: Please update your example with your new code.

Comment: yes,i had update this code and resut!

Comment: You've still got one `std::thread::sleep`

Comment: yes！you are right，it,s run expectant。

Answer (score 3):

Don't use **anything** that blocks in tokio, or async in general. Async tasks are **non-preemptive**, also called **cooperative multi-tasking**. They cannot be preempted (unscheduled) unless they idle at an `.await` point.

[`std::thread::sleep`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) does **not** provide an `.await` point, so waiting at it will **block the entire runtime** (or parts of the runtime in the multi-threaded case).

Quintessence: **Never call `std::thread::sleep` in an `async` function.**

Use [`tokio::time::sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) instead; it **does** provide an `.await` point, allowing the runtime to switch to another task while sleeping.

In fact, your entire `use std::time;` and `use std::thread::sleep;` are red flags. Remove those alltogether.

Here is your fixed code:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

static REQUEST_RECV_V2: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

async fn no_msg_pro(s: String) {
    println!("execute no_msg_pro fun - str: {} begin!", s);
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
    println!("execute no_msg_pro fun - str: {} end!", s);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        loop {
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            REQUEST_RECV_V2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            let s = format!("value--{:?}", REQUEST_RECV_V2);
            println!("run process_msg fun - handle: {:?}", s);
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                no_msg_pro(s).await;
            });
        }
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
}
```

```
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--1"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--1 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--1 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--2"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--2 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--2 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--3"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--3 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--3 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--4"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--4 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--4 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--5"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--5 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--5 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--6"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--6 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--6 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--7"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--7 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--7 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--8"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--8 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--8 end!
run process_msg fun - handle: "value--9"
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--9 begin!
execute no_msg_pro fun - str: value--9 end!
```

Comment: cool ! you're right，i had solve the problem by ideas obtained from here。

Comment: Unrelated, but your keyboard seems to print the wrong `.` at the end of sentences. I'm not even sure what that character is. Just fyi.